# How to send data to server on click of button in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to post some data to shiny server at the submit event of a button. I have done the input binding but I am not able to recieve the data on the server my html and server code are.

```
<html>
<script>
   var submit_binding = new Shiny.InputBinding();
   $.extend(submit_binding, {
        find: function(scope) {
             return $(scope).find("#submit");
         },

       getValue: function(el) {
           // Get the row and cell number of the selected td.
           //var month 
           //var year 
           var result = ['2', '2013'];
           return result;
        },

       subscribe: function(el, callback) {
           $(el).on("click.submit_binding", function(e) {
               callback();
           });
       },

       unsubscribe: function(el) {
            $(el).off(".submit_binding");
       }

       });

     Shiny.inputBindings.register(submit_binding);
</script>
    <body>
    <div>
        <select id="mn" name="mn">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select> 
        <select id="yr" name="yr">
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
        </select> 
        <button id="submit">Run</button>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div  id="mean" class="d3-plot-output"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Server Code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    month <- reactive({
        switch(input$mn, '1'=1, '2'=2,1)
    })
    year <- reactive({
        switch(input$yr, '2012'=2012, '2013'=2013,2012)
    })

    testwrite <- function(){
         a = c[1,2,3]       
         write.csv(a, file="test_binding.csv");
         return (a)
}

    output$mean <- reactive(        
        testwrite()
    )
 })
```

I am not able to figure out what am I missing here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I don't think you need a binding to communicate between server and client. If you clarify what you are trying to do, someone can help.

Comment: I have a html page where I have a select boxes and submit button. Upon making selections and hitting the submit button I will be sending the selection box values to the server. The server will run some functions and the results will be sent back to the client. The client will then draw some charts using d3js.

Comment: Shiny already has a submit button for this purpose. Is that insufficient for your purpose?

Comment: I am not using shiny ui. I am using a custom HTML.

Comment: You can still use existing bindings by adding the right classes. So for submit button, you add `type=submit`.

Comment: I tried that but I was not able to get the data at the server

Comment: Shiny identifies inputs by id or name. So you can access it on the server as `input$name`, where name is the id/name of the input element.

Comment: I am using input$submit in my server where the id of the submit button is submit. But not working

Comment: Hmm is this your actual HTML? I suggest you run a Shiny example e.g. shiny::runExample("01_hello") right click on the web page and select view source. You are missing alot of shiny boiler-plates. E.g you did not include shiny.js in your html. Even if your binding code is perfect it will not work!!

Comment: The boiler plate is removed here for brevity of the question but actual code includes all that.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my server code as below to get it working

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues();
    values$lastAction <- NULL;
    observe({    
        values$lastAction <- input$submit;
    })    

    testwrite <- function(){
         a = c[1,2,3]       
         write.csv(a, file="test_binding.csv");
         return (a)
    }

    output$mean <- function(){        
        if(!is.null(values$lastAction)){
            testwrite()                
        }
    }
})
```